# Saving an Incremental Game Locally

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get my incremental game to save cookies/data locally, but am not sure how to do it.. Here's the HTML and the Javascript.

Javascript:

```
    saveGame() = function() {
    saveService.saveGame();
    }

    resetGame() = function() {
    localStorage.clear();
    }
```

HTML:

```
                    <section><center>
                        <p>The game auto-saves every 30 seconds, but in case you are in a hurry, use this:</p><br />
                        <a class="button12" ng-click="saveGame()"/>Save Game</a>
                        <br /><br />
                    </center></section>
                        <hr>
                    <section><center>
                        <p>This will <strong>permanently</strong> reset your game (refresh after you press it):</p><br />
                        <a class="button12" ng-click="resetGame()">Reset Game</a>
                        <br /><br />
                    </center></section>
```

In addition to saving your game, I also want to be able to have the game be able to get reset. How could I do that as well?

Comment: How does `saveService.saveGame();` look?

Comment: I really don't understand the question.. :c The Javascript isn't mine, I didn't author it, so I don't believe I can answer the question.

Comment: Storing game data in localStorage is a bad idea in the first place tbh, since you're limited to a couple of MB in space. Look in to web databases like indexDb.

Comment: Alright, I guess I can try to figure that out. Thanks for the advice! :3

Comment: Depends on how much space is required.